# Angular 6 header code not been called when using router

Tags: angular

ts after validating username and password I do:

```
this.router.navigate(['./home']);
```

I use a header on every page that has:

```
<ng-container *ngIf='isAuthenticated'>

<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#" (click)="logout()"> 
 logout</a>
  </li>

 </ng-container>
```

at the header.ts

```
 export class HeaderComponent {

  isAuthenticated: boolean;

  constructor(private security: SecurityService, private 
  router: Router) {
  this.isAuthenticated = security.isLogged();
 }
```

the issue is that `security.isLogged()` doesn't get called, so `isAuthenticated` is always `false` or `undefined`.
It looks like `this.router.navigate(['./home']);` change the content of the component but not the header's component.
The redirect works only for the main component of the page only.
If after been redirected I manually refresh the page from the browser it works.

The routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginFormComponent} from './login-form/login- 
form.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [

{
 path: 'home',
 component: HomeComponent
},
{
 path: 'login',
 component: LoginFormComponent
}

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The constructor will not be called again from the looks of it. Instead, consider using an `Observable` in the `SecurityService` so that you can update any components when the `isLoggedIn` value changes

Comment: isLoggedIn value won't change if is not called

Comment: How does the header component know that the value of `isLoggedIn` has changed?

Comment: Buy the way is isAuthenticated Only when the constructor has been called and thus this.isAuthenticated = security.isLogged(); get executed

Comment: @EyalRosenzvaig Please try the code I have posted as answer. I think that should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could use a messaging structure to inform the header component of the changes. Like below:

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ShareDataService {
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  sendMessage(message: any) {
    this.subject.next({ obj: message });
  }

  clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Once you have the service defined, in the header.ts,

```
subscription: Subscription;
constructor(
  private sharedService: ShareDataService) {

  this.subscription = this.sharedService.getMessage()
    .subscribe((message) => {
    // your code here
  });
}
```

In the component that verifies login, once login is successful, send a message like below

```
this.shareDataService.sendMessage(value); --value being any data you want to send to 
header
```

Any time the value of isLoggedIn is changed, make a call to this sendMessage so that the header component subscribes to it and knows that a change has occurred and should act accordingly.

### The above is implemented in Angular5

Comment: sorry for the delay I tried your suggestion but it is not working I did put this.subscription = this.sharedService.getMessage()
    .subscribe((message) => {
      this.checkSecondNav(); where the code need to be executed but first at login I did this.shareDataService.sendMessage('blabla') before redirecting, but still not forcing the code to be executed

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I had a very similar issue and I think I found the answer:

[how to force function in app component to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460531/how-to-force-function-in-app-component-to-be-called)

the key is to have the code you want to be executed under a subscription or reactive method as it was pointed out in the answer at the link above by callOfCode, in tried his suggestion and it works.