# how to force function in app component to be called

Tags: angular

Because of the second level navigation menu I have logic code on app module

app.component.html

```
<clr-main-container>
   <app-header *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-header>
   <div class="content-container">
      <main class="content-area">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </main>
      <nav *ngIf="showSecondNav" class="sidenav" [clr-nav-level]="2">
         <section class="sidenav-content">
             <a class="nav-link nav-text" routerLink="/users">Users</a> 
         </section>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <app-footer *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-footer>
</clr-main-container>
```

after login I redirect to `/home` expecting to go through the logic code on app.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.isLogged = this.credentialsService.isAuthenticated();

this.router.events
  .subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/login')
    }
  });
  this.checkSecondNav();

}   

checkSecondNav(){
  if(this.headerFooter && this.isLogged){
    this.showSecondNav = true;
    console.log('showSeconNav:' + this.showSecondNav);
  }

}
```

but that code it's never called going from `/login` to `/home`

I can't change the location of second level navagation menu in app.module.

How can I force to call `checkSecondNav()` after redirecting from login, that constructor (at app.component.ts) is not called.

at login.component.ts

```
 if(this.user.token != null){
        this.credentials.username = this.user.name;
        this.credentials.token = this.user.token;


  this.credentialsService.setCredentials(
  this.credentials,this.loginForm.value.rememberMe);
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }else{
    this.wrongCredentials = "wrong credentials";

  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if constructor is called so put one condition there if comes form login called checkSecondNav() function

Comment: that constructor is not called , that's the problem

Comment: can you show login.component.ts and html

Comment: This seems like the type of thing you may want to do inside of a Guard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing reactive/imperative approaches.

Value of `this.isLogged` is always the same as it was when `ngOnInit` was called.
Reactive approach would be to combine multiple observables e.g. `isAuthenticated$` and `currentRoute$` (postfix `$` means `Observable` by naming convention).

Like this:

```
const currentRoute$ = this.router.events.pipe(
                              filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd), 
                              map(event => event.url)
                      );
//Credentials service should have observable property. You can achieve it with subject
const isAuthenticated$ = this.credentialsService.isAuthenticated$;

this.footerVisible$ = currentRoute$.pipe(map(route => route !== '/login'))

this.showSecondNav$ = combineLatest(this.footerVisible$, isAuthenticated$)
                            .pipe(map(([footerVisible, authenticated]) => footerVisible && authenticated))
```

And in your app.component.html:

```
<clr-main-container>
   <app-header *ngIf="headerFooter"></app-header>
   <div class="content-container">
      <main class="content-area">
         <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </main>
      <nav *ngIf="showSecondNav$ | async" class="sidenav" [clr-nav-level]="2">
         <section class="sidenav-content">
             <a class="nav-link nav-text" routerLink="/users">Users</a> 
         </section>
      </nav>
   </div>
   <app-footer *ngIf="footerVisible$ | async"></app-footer>
</clr-main-container>
```

I am not sure if this is the logic you wanted, but you've got the idea about reactive approach.

If you still want to use imperative approach, just put everything in subscriber:

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
    this.isLogged = this.credentialsService.isAuthenticated();
    this.headerFooter = event.url !== '/login';
    this.checkSecondNav();
  }
});
```

If you need to secure particular places of application from unauthorized users, use guards for this and not `*ngIf`.

Comment: Yes great it is working perfectly now, i putted everything under the reactive method, works great, thank you very much   this.router.events
      .subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.headerFooter = (event.url !== '/login');
          this.isLogged = this.credentialsService.isAuthenticated();
          this.checkSecondNav();
        }
      });